# What species of berry is this?

Tags: identification, shrubs, berries

This is a berry bush outside my workplace. What species is it? I can easily get more pictures if that would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this had white flowers on it a few weeks ago, and assuming that you're in North America, I'd say that the shrub is a Chokeberry (*Aronia melanocarpa*). The shrub might be about 3 feet high and wide, unless trimmed by your workplace's maintenance people. If I'm right, then the berries are edible, but only if cooked first (too bitter otherwise - hence "choke" berry). They apparently make very good juice.

Comment: Wasn't in the office till recently, so unsure on the white flowers, but the rest of the description fits. I'll wait 24 hours and accept your answer if no one else chimes in. Thanks!

Comment: Later in the summer the berries should turn a very dark blue-black. Aronia also has excellent fall foliage (scarlet and orange, mostly).